# HTML Validation Error: Bad value tooltip for attribute rel on element a: Keyword tooltip is not registered

Tags: validation, rel

Should I be concerned with the following HTML validation error?

```
        …rel="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" data-original-title="Permalink"></a></li>
        Syntax of link type valid for <a> and <area>:
        A whitespace-separated list of link types listed as allowed on <a> and <area> in the HTML specification or listed as an allowed on <a> and <area> on the Microformats wiki without duplicate keywords in the list. You can register link types on the Microformats wiki yourself.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `rel` value `tooltip` is not allowed in HTML5.

You can use the [`rel` values listed in the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html#linkTypes), or the [registered `rel` values in the microformats wiki](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#HTML5_link_type_extensions).

Note that `tooltip` is listed in the microformats wiki (in the [POSH usage](http://microformats.org/wiki/existing-rel-values#POSH_usage) section), but not in the section "HTML5 link type extensions".

Answer (score 4):

"rel" value tooltip is not a valid attribute in html 5.

Replace `rel` attribute  with `data-rel` attribute (wich is absolutely valid) in your code.

**example:**

`$("a[rel]").tooltip();` to `$("a[data-rel]").tooltip();`